# I want to create a really simple cross platform browser in C++. Where to begin?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

All I want the browser to do right now is fetch a webpage (www.google.com) off the internet. Does boost Asio provide all the functionality I need? What library can provide the functionality I need?

@ perreal - I want both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at [Qt](http://www.qt-project.org/) because it already has a webkit framework, is cross-platform portable and you could get a minimally working version up and running in probably less than 100 lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous C and C++ libraries out there that can be used to perform simple socket operations, and numerous libraries that can support simple HTTP GET requests.

However, that is far from creating a browser. Browsers do a lot of things beyond simply opening sockets, such as compression, encryption, caching, rendering, interpretation, etc.

If your goal is simply to make an HTTP GET request, then `libcurl` is one possible library you can look at. I am sure there are others out there. If you actually want to create a full-fledged browser, you might want to start by modifying an existing browser. Chromium, the opensource project behind Chrome, which is based on the WebKit rendering engine would be a good place to start.